# How to check that Genesis Block has valid proof of work using CheckProofOfWork() function?

Tags: testnet, proof-of-work, genesis-block

I have been learning the ins and outs of the bitcoin source code over the past 3 months but I can say I have not fully mastered it yet. I wish to understand how the genesis block is validated using the CheckProofOfWork() function. I would like to do something like this in chainsparams.cpp:

while (!CheckProofOfWork(block.GetHash(), block.nBits, chainparams.GetConsensus())) ++block.nNonce;

Where I seem to be stuck is how to obtain chainparams.GetConsensus() inside of chainsparams.cpp

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: I am also stuck at this stage... searched a lot, but none... Have you found anything?

Comment: And what is variable 'block'? Isn't it 'genesis' variable in newest source?